# Javascript - run dynamically loaded script before inline script

Tags: javascript

I've got some dynamically loaded JS files I'm loading like so:

```
javascripts.forEach(function(src) {
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.async = false;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
});
```

(Where javascripts is an array of files.)

This script is run by a JS file loaded in the head. The problem I'm having is the files that are dynamically being loaded are not being run until after some script that is included inside  tags in the body that depend on the JS that is being dynamically loaded.

I thought that since the files are being added in the head they would run before the body, but they aren't. What am I doing wrong?

(And I know I should just get rid of the inline script, but unfortunately I only control the one JS file and I need to somehow leverage it to make a fix by dynamically loading more JS files.)

Comment: I don't remember if it works, but you could try `document.write('<script src="' + script + '"<\/script>')` instead of adding it with appendChild.

Comment: You can simplify your code a bit using `document.head.appendChild(...)`.  No need to get it by the tag name.